# Git to correct branch and worktree mismatch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-worktree

Following up on ['<Branch>' is already checked out at '</other/location>' in git worktrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41545293/)

I'm getting the "`Branch is already checked out at different worktree`" error when my branch and worktree mismatched:

I have to use `git worktree remove` to remove my 1.2T worktree for now, but I'd like to know what's the best way to fix it in the future.

I have branch and worktree setup like the following:

- `/path/master` corresponds to my git `master` branch
- `/path/release-a` corresponds to my git `release-a` branch
- `/path/release-b` corresponds to my git `release-b` branch

So on and so forth. I had it like that for years, until a few days ago I click and change a worktree branch in MS VS *by mistake*. Now my branch and worktree is like this:

- `/path/release-a` is using my git `release-b` branch
- `/path/release-b` is using my git `release-b` branch

Now I cannot change it back in MS VS. Trying to switch branch within the worktree will get me:

```
fatal: '<branch>' is already checked out at '</other/location>'
```

Any better way other than `git worktree remove` please.

Comment: Consider running `git worktree prune` as in my answer there.

Comment: Thanks but I've tried `git worktree prune` before posting here. I.e., it didn't help the above situation.

Comment: Hm, that suggests that VS is doing a `git worktree lock`. The latest Git (2.31 now) might have an improvement that's been in the works to make `git worktree list` show more information about the set of work-trees it knows (or thinks it knows) about, which might help here. Not sure what the state of this is at this time though.

Comment: Thanks torek, I did looked up and tried `git worktree list` before, I've lost the output (due to my Windows machine was forcefully rebooted), but I do think there is nothing special about the mismatched worktree, else I'd have noticed and asked alone that route. I could be wrong though (or my git is not recent enough). Thanks for the info, may it help the next victim.

Comment: My question would be how you managed to change one of your work trees to have a branch checked out that you already had checked out in a different work tree. In other words, when whatever checked out `release-b` in `/path/release-a`, why didn't *that* command also get that same error message? Basically, you shouldn't be able to end up in this kind of situation.

Comment: As I have explained, _"I click and change a worktree branch in MS VS by mistake"_. You've got to have used MS VS to understand that black magic.

Comment: This corruption can be recreated by editing `<repo-path>/.git/worktrees/release-a/HEAD` to `ref: refs/heads/release-b`. How to undo that curroption is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, if the layout is as you described, you should just be able to `git switch release-a` within `/path/release-a`. Does your question reflect the output of `git worktree list`, or what you see in MSVS?

If the `.git` metadata is messed up, you could create dummy branches (`git checkout -b dummy-x`, `dummy-y` etc) in both worktrees, then `git switch release-...` back in each one. Commit / stash as necessary if there is unsaved work in the worktrees.

If MSVS stores metadata elsewhere, that's a different problem which presumably can only be solved within MSVS.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there is a `git switch` release-a command. Will accept it as the answer for the time being. Thanks!

Comment: @xpt “for the time being.” This seems like the correct forever-answer.