# Create a worktree for a project using submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-worktree

I have a top project, with about 10 submodules, and some nested submodules.

```
./top-project/
./top-project/module-a
./top-project/module-b
...
```

Some submodules have a classic url, like `url = git:software/module-a`, other have an url relative remote top-project like `url = ../module-b`. top-project url is `url = git:software/top-project`.

I want to create a worktree copy of top-project, AND all its submodules.

```
git worktree add -f ../top-project-v2
```

But I can't find a way making the submodules pointing to their original path. I would like that `top-project-v2/module-a` git pointing to `top-project/module-a`, and not cloning a brand new module-a.

If I do `cd top-project-v2; git submodule upate --init --recursive`, the command succeeds but submodules are not linked to top-project submodules.

If I do `git checkout --recurse-submodules origin/v2`, I get an error:

```
git checkout --recurse-submodules origin/v2
fatal: not a git repository: ../../top-project/.git/worktrees/top-project-v2/modules/module-a
fatal: could not reset submodule index
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Nope. No solution so far. But I did not use subtree + submodules for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If the submodules are not optional or cheap enough to fetch anyway, carry the submodule histories in the main repo as branches and `git submodule init; git worktree add` for them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely, submodules are still not supported. At least for the current version (2.43.0) the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree#_bugs)  still tells that support for it is "incomplete":

> Multiple checkout in general is still experimental, and the support for submodules is incomplete. It is NOT recommended to make multiple checkouts of a superproject.

[I've created a `post-checkout` hook](https://gitlab.com/doak/super-worktree/-/blob/main/super-worktree.post-checkout) which makes it possible to add a worktree for a super repository, but since it is not triggered atfer e.g. `git submodule update` there may occasions where it does not work. You are able to trigger the hook at anytime using `git checkout @`.

Short usage:

- Execute `super-worktree.post-checkout --install` from within the super project.
- Create a worktree with `git worktree add <path>` as usual.
- You should then `cd` into the worktree and execute `git submodule update && git checkout @`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872051/4138912 for an explanation of the "current" implementation.