# When would you not want to develop in a git linked worktree?

Tags: git

I am thinking of working exclusively in linked worktrees rather than the "main worktree" (the repo from which the command `git worktree add ../another-worktree` is run).

This means that on my local desktop computer, there will only ever be one main worktree for each git repo.

I am wondering if there are any issues/constraints I will run into when doing this. For example, IntelliJ used to not work correctly with linked worktrees, but I think this is fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would I use git-worktree for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935776/what-would-i-use-git-worktree-for)

Comment: `git worktree` [is not compatible with submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31871888/7976758). As I use submodules almost everywhere I don't use `git worktree`s — just full clones.

Comment: What’s the motivation for this approach?